# updating string array inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

I define a string array in main function, and I want to update it inside another function as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 15

void read_arrays(char *competitors[SIZE], float points[SIZE], int numOfCompetitors)
{
        for (int cntr = 0; cntr < numOfCompetitors; cntr++)
        {
                printf("Enter the name of competitor %d", cntr+1);
                scanf("%s", &*competitors[cntr]);
                printf("Enter the point of competitor %d", cntr+1);
                scanf("%f", &points[cntr]);
        }
}

int main()
{
        char *competitors[SIZE];
        float points[SIZE];
        int numOfCompetitors = 0;
        while (numOfCompetitors > 15 || numOfCompetitors < 1)
        {
                printf("Enter the number of competitors: ");
                scanf("%d", &numOfCompetitors);
                if (numOfCompetitors > 15) printf("Number of competitors cannot be more than 15!\n");
        }

        read_arrays(&*competitors[SIZE], &points[SIZE], numOfCompetitors);
        printf("%f", points[0]);

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
cc     homework2.c   -o homework2
homework2.c: In function ‘main’:
homework2.c:28:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read_arrays’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  read_arrays(&*competitors[SIZE], &points[SIZE], numOfCompetitors);
              ^
homework2.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void read_arrays(char *competitors[SIZE], float points[SIZE], int numOfCompetitors)
```

I want to assign the values in array of strings with scanf in a loop. How I can manage to do that?

Comment: `read_arrays(competitors, points, numOfCompetitors);`?

Comment: You have not allocated memory to elements of the pointer array `char *competitors[SIZE];` . So `scanf` is taking an indeterminate pointer in `scanf("%s", &*competitors[cntr]);` — which should be `scanf("%s", competitors[cntr]);` anyway, because it is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the name of the variable when you pass it to the function, you also need to specify the size of the char matrix (~ array of strings).

So this: `read_arrays(&*competitors[SIZE], &points[SIZE], numOfCompetitors);`

Becomes: `read_arrays(competitors, points, numOfCompetitors);`

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 15

void read_arrays(char competitors[SIZE][30], float points[SIZE], int numOfCompetitors)
{
    for (int cntr = 0; cntr < numOfCompetitors; cntr++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of competitor %d", cntr+1);
        // We read up to 29 characters => no overflow as the size is up to 30
        scanf("%29s", competitors[cntr]);
        printf("Enter the point of competitor %d", cntr+1);
        scanf("%f", &points[cntr]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char competitors[SIZE][30];
    float points[SIZE];
    int numOfCompetitors = 0;
    while (numOfCompetitors > 15 || numOfCompetitors < 1)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of competitors: ");
        scanf("%d", &numOfCompetitors);
        if (numOfCompetitors > 15) printf("Number of competitors cannot be more than 15!\n");
    }

    read_arrays(competitors, points, numOfCompetitors);

    printf("%s", competitors[0]);
    printf("%s", competitors[1]);
    printf("%f", points[0]);
}
```

Comment: `*&` is pointless. Also, `scanf` `%s` is a bug (buffer overflow).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Daniel Illescas you could just allocate space for each competitor that you input.  Just be sure to free them later.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 15

void read_arrays(char *competitors[SIZE], float points[SIZE], int numOfCompetitors)
{
    for (int cntr = 0; cntr < numOfCompetitors; cntr++)
    {
        competitors[cntr] = (char*)calloc(1, 32);
        printf("Enter the name of competitor %d", cntr + 1);
        scanf("%s", competitors[cntr]);
        printf("Enter the point of competitor %d", cntr + 1);
        scanf("%f", &points[cntr]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *competitors[SIZE];
    float points[SIZE];
    int numOfCompetitors = 0;
    while (numOfCompetitors > 15 || numOfCompetitors < 1)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of competitors: ");
        scanf("%d", &numOfCompetitors);
        if (numOfCompetitors > 15) printf("Number of competitors cannot be more than 15!\n");
    }

    read_arrays(competitors, points, numOfCompetitors);
    printf("%f", points[0]);

}
```